# iOS app is syncing and installed in ios6, but not installed in ios 5 & below?

Tags: iphone, ios, ios5, ios6

We have developed an iOS application that supports both iOS5 and iOS6. The problem is that the ipa file is successfully synced and installed in iOS6 but it is not installed in iOS5. Please share your suggestion. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please share you info.plist file

Comment: I am also facing the same issue.. Any help would be appreciated..

Answer (score 0):

Probably your deployment target is 6.0. That's why it is not installing on iOS 5 devices.

If you need to install application on device then the deployment target of the application should be less than or equal to the iOS device's OS version.

**Set the deployment target to 5.0.**

Also check whether you added the device's UDID to the provisioning profile (if you are using development certificates)

Comment: i have set to 4.3, but still it is not

Comment: @Gowtham: did your provisioning profile have added the iOS 5 device's UDID ?